# fixed amount of delay to all packets using command tc

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

i try to adds a fixed amount of delay to all packets using this command ( # tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms )

after typing 
show me "Cannot find device "eth0"

Answer (score 3):

Type the command

> ifconfig -a

and check the interface names. Maybe you dont
have it like eth0 and you have it configured on eth1

You could check the configuration too in

> /etc/network/interfaces

if you are working on debian/ubuntu system.

Give us some more information.